# Playwright proxy per context is not working as it should

Tags: javascript, playwright

Playwright proxy per context not working, its coming up with the error "Uncaught Error page.goto: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED at [https://www.whatismyip.com/"](https://www.whatismyip.com/%22)

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {

    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
        headless: false,
        proxy: { server: 'per-context' }
    });

    const context = await browser.newContext();

    const page = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        page[0] = await context.newPage({
            proxy: {
                server: 'http://193.8.138.32:9575',
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }
        });

        await page[0].goto('https://www.whatismyip.com');

    }
    
})();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.